# Setting up a wildcard subdomain in Apache

Tags: apache, redirect

Help me configure the following logic: when `example.ru` is requested, the content from `var/www/example.ru` should be displayed. When `*.example.ru` is requested, the content from var/www/subdomain should be displayed (where * represents any subdomain, like `admin.example.ru`).

I'm trying it like this, but it's not working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@example.ru
    ServerName example.ru
    ServerAlias *.example.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.ru

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.ru
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.ru$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/subdomain/$1 [L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break it up into two virtual hosts and set the `DocumentRoot` for each of them. No need to use rewrite rules at all.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@example.ru
    ServerName example.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.ru
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@example.ru
    ServerName sub.example.ru
    ServerAlias *.example.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```